# How to have search functionality using EditText for recycler view for android app?

Tags: android, android-studio, kotlin

I have implemented following logic for search option in `CustomAdapter.kt` file.

```
class CustomAdapter(public val context: Context, private val countriesResponse: CountriesResponse) :
RecyclerView.Adapter<CustomAdapter.MyViewHolder>(), Filterable{

var country : ArrayList<String>? = null
var list_country : ArrayList<String>? = null
internal var mFilter : NewFilter

override fun getFilter(): Filter {
    return mFilter
}

init {
    list_country = getCountries()
    country = ArrayList()
    country!!.addAll(list_country!!)
    mFilter = NewFilter(this@CustomAdapter)
}

private fun getCountries(): ArrayList<String>? {
    val list_country = arrayListOf<String>()
    for (list1 in 0..countriesResponse.size)
        list_country.add(list1.toString())
    return list_country
}


class MyViewHolder(itemView: View) : RecyclerView.ViewHolder(itemView) {

    var image: ImageView
    var cv_tv_country_name: TextView

    init {
        image = itemView.cv_iv_country_flag
        cv_tv_country_name = itemView.cv_tv_country_name
    }
}


val VIEW_TYPE = 1

override fun onCreateViewHolder(parent: ViewGroup, viewType: Int): MyViewHolder {
    var itemView = LayoutInflater.from(context).inflate(R.layout.flag_list, parent, false)
    return MyViewHolder(itemView)
}

override fun getItemCount(): Int {
    return list_country!!.size
}

override fun onBindViewHolder(holder: MyViewHolder, position: Int) {
    Glide.with(context).load(countriesResponse[position].countryInfo.flag).into(holder.image)
    holder.itemView.setOnClickListener {
        val intent =
            Intent(context, CountryWiseDataActivity::class.java).putExtra("position", position)
        context.startActivity(intent)
    }
    holder.cv_tv_country_name.text = countriesResponse[position].country
}

inner class NewFilter(var customAdapter: CustomAdapter): Filter(){
    override fun performFiltering(constraint: CharSequence?): FilterResults {
        country!!.clear()
        val results = FilterResults()
        if (constraint!!.length == 0){
            country!!.addAll(list_country!!)
        } else {
            val filterPattern = constraint.toString().toLowerCase().trim() { it <= ' '}
            for (list_country in list_country!!) {
                if (list_country.toLowerCase().contains(filterPattern)){
                    country!!.add(list_country) //This line is not getting executed
                }
            }
        }

        results.values = country  // Here I am getting null
        results.count = country!!.size
        return results
    }

    override fun publishResults(constraint: CharSequence?, results: FilterResults?) {
        this.customAdapter.notifyDataSetChanged()
    }

}
```

Now in the `Activity`I have implemented `TextWatcher`. My code is as below `Countries.kt` file.

```
search_countries.addTextChangedListener(object : TextWatcher {
        override fun afterTextChanged(s: Editable?) {

        }

        override fun beforeTextChanged(s: CharSequence?, start: Int, count: Int, after: Int) {

        }

        override fun onTextChanged(s: CharSequence?, start: Int, before: Int, count: Int) {
            countryAdapter.getFilter().filter(s.toString())
            countryAdapter.notifyDataSetChanged()
        }

    })
```

`search_countries` is the id of EditText which is provided in my `LayoutFile`.

I am fetching the countries from an `RESTAPI` and there is total of `215` countries in the list. I have completed the necessary implementation and I am wondering that why my search function is not working??

Comment: are you using repository pattern? if you are searching directly from from frontend to backend then you need network call for searching item... like.. www.listcountry/specficid/countryname there will be url something like this.. in specfic id query you have to add search id to search items or searchName... the other way is to cache the data from network to localDB(roomdatabase) using repisotory pattern then search from roomdatabase using search query...

Comment: @USMANosman: I have successfully fetched the data from `RESTAPI`. I am implementing a search bar from which user can search the countries what they want. Also I don't want to use database as I am displaying LiveData to the app (No Need to store the data).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

From what I can tell, your code is doing this:

- in the init block, `list_country` is set to a list of country indices, from 0 to [`countryResponse.size`] (should this be country names instead?)
- `country` is also a list of country indices - it's initialised to the same full list as `list_countries`
- the filter code clears `country`, and then fills it with all the elements in `list_country` that match the search term
- `list_country` contains a bunch of indices though, "0"..."214" so unless you're typing in numbers nothing will match
- `country` ends up empty (shouldn't be null?)

I think it would help if you renamed `listCountries` to something like `allCountryIndices` and `countries` to `filteredCountryIndices` or something like that, so it's clear exactly what they are. You want to run all your filtering on the contents of `countriesResponse`, right?

---

Also in `onBindViewHolder` (where a list item works out what data it needs to display) you're taking a list `position` and using that as an index in `countriesResponse` - that's fine when your list contains all the countries so each position matches an item in `countriesResponse`, but when you filter your list you'll only have a few items, and the item at position 0 probably won't be item 0 in `countriesResponse`, you know?

If `country` is your list of filtered `countryResponse` indices, you want to grab `country[position]` to get the right ID. Also `getItemCount` should be using `country.size` - that's your actual list you're displaying, which might be all the countries or a few if it's filtered. `listCountry` is just a reference of all the indices (which you don't really need?)

---

btw if you make `country` and `listCountry` non-null (you never need to set them to null in your code) you'll save yourself a lot of headaches and won't need to put `!!` everywhere! Like:

```
var country : ArrayList<String>
var list_country : ArrayList<String>
```

you assign them in the `init` block so it's ok. (really they could be `val` since you assign them once, but I don't want to overcomplicate stuff! It does make your life easier in Kotlin though)

Comment: 1.) Yes `countriesResponse` contains all the country names. 2.) Yes, that is right that I want to run all my filtering on the contents of `countriesResponse`. 3.) So, in `onBindViewHolder` instead of `countriesResponse` I have to write `country[position]`. ?

Comment: You are right that I have to change the names of `list_countries` and `country` so it should be clear. I will do that.

Comment: Your filtering code needs to look at each country name, so something like ``if (countriesResponse[list_country].countryName.toLowerCase().contains(filterPattern))`` or however you access it. You're using the indices to look up each entry, and then grabbing the name to check if it matches the filter

Comment: ``onBindViewHolder`` is about your current list in the ``RecyclerView`` - which really needs to represent all the entries in ``country``, right? ``country`` is the stuff you want to display, which might be all the countries (containing all the entries in ``list_country``) or it might be a few (when you filter the list you rewrite ``country`` so it only contains the matching countries). So each ``position`` value matches the same index in ``country``, so you go ``country[position]``. And that gives you the index of a country in ``countriesResponse``. So ``countriesResponse[country[position]]``